# undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 id's stored in the database. I have not touched 'spec' folder. but still `localhost:3000/users/1` is showing this error.

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #1):
1: <%= @user.name %>, <%= @user.email %>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
  end
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= @user.name %>, <%= @user.email %>
```

**models - > users.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

Comment: is your routing correct?  `resources user`

Comment: check in your database if there is `user` with `id=1`. Also can you update question with application log for the `show` action.

Comment: Please paste your application log.

Comment: Try in command line `rails c`, then `User.all`, and `rake routes`. And add the result to your question.

Comment: @Tetsu `rake routes` in console? It would raise `undefined local variable or method 'routes'`.

Comment: @Marek sorry, I should have written more clearer. In command line `rails c`, then `User.all`, and exit rails console, then `rake routes`.

Comment: `users.rb` - mistake?

Answer (score -2):

Edit show.html.erb Like bellow:

```
<%- if @user.present? %>
  <%= @user.name %>, <%= @user.email %>
<%end%>
```

The issue is arise due to @user is nil. So yu should check either the object of user is nil or not. Then Process the object as per your requirements.

Comment: Yeah, right, but the main problem here is why `@user` is `nil`, since it seems to be set in controller. Plus it's not a good practice to show blank show page.

Comment: @MarekLipka, In Controller, you write bad code that never handle exception if there is no user by finding id. So what the solution expected by you by writing the above code? You should manage either it in controller respective action or in view. I just suggest you a solution. That's it.

Comment: Your solution doesn't solve anything, since the problem here is why `@user` is `nil`. Plus, in `show` action, the error should be thrown if there is no record with given id. Your solution attempt just gives user blank page and he doesn't even know what's happening.